# CoreBluetooth - Generic Access (1800) for a Peripherial implemented on iPhone?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm implemening the peripherial role in the iOS app and I was able to succesfully configure custom service which is being advertised and can be accessed.

Now it looks that I cannot change the Generic Acccess Profile values, like Device Name - I am adding a CBMutableService configured for "1800" but in the scan list I still see "GENERIC PHONE" value.

Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service isn't its own peripheral. It's part of a shared peripheral for the whole device (phone). So you don't directly control the GAP, you just provide services.

That said, setting the advertisement name of the peripheral while you're in control is straightforward. You just pass it with `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` in the `startAdvertising` dictionary:

```
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{
    CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MY_SERVICE_UUID]],
    CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : @"MyDevice"
}];
```

Note that the only things you can control are the local name and the service UUIDs. You can't set things like the manufacturer data, transmit power, etc.

Comment: Thanks, was somehow very hard to find this information in original docs. I can set the device name now, except Service 1800 still reports generic phone but that's not changeable I see now.